# How to store json values into into different sheets of a csv file by using Angular5csv?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to store different data values in a csv file but in different csv. I have json datas for different tables of my component and I want to save the data into different sheet.

For example datasets could be like this for one table:

```
var data1 = [
      {
        name: "Test 1",
        age: 13,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      },
      {
        name: "Test 2",
        age: 11,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      },
      {
        name: "Test 4",
        age: 10,
        average: 8.2,
        approved: true,
        description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
      }
    ];
var data2 = [
      {
       ........
      },
      {
        .......
      },
      {
       .......
      }
    ];
```

Now for these two datasets I want to create two different sheets in a single CSV file.

```js
 var options = {
      fieldSeparator: ",",
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: ".",
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: true,
      title: "Your title",
      useBom: true,
      noDownload: true,
      headers: ["First Name", "Last Name", "ID"]
    };

    new Angular5Csv(data, "My Report");
```

Please also mention if I could use any other packages to make the thing easy.

Thank you for your time here.

Comment: try looking into this https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx